# Import only those cells from a spreadsheet that have certain conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, conditional-formatting, importrange

I have created a Google Form which links to a spreadsheet. There is an option which asks for the person's name. For the answers in the sheet, I've created conditional formatting to highlight the correct answers.

```
=importrange(" xxxx ", "xxx!xxx" )
```

I want it to be able to import the names from the `name` column that have answered all the questions correctly to another sheet if possible. I know the import code, however I need help with importing specific names that have all the cells highlighted with conditional formatting.

Comment: The built-in functions can't read the conditional formatting rules and I think that Google Apps Script can't do this either. You should consider to add your validation rules to an auxiliary column or to a script.

Comment: @Rubén if you know how to add validation rules, request to edit to help please

Comment: See the [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/92962/88163) by [sandwich](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/79865/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rubén said, conditional formatting is  for human consumption only: neither sheet formulas nor scripts can access it. You should create a column that records the fact of "all answers are correct", and then filter by that column. For example, put in E2

```
=arrayformula((C2:C=2)*(D2:D=4))
```

which will put 1 in every row where both answers are correct. Then execute `query` command on the result of `importrange`:

```
=query(importrange("...", "'Form Responses 1'!B:E"), "select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col4 = 1", 1)
```

Comment: the query command does not work it gives a #Value! error. "Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMNB"

Comment: Indeed, the columns of an imported range must be referenced as Col1, Col2, and so on. Corrected.